# How does Visual Studio fill 'Dependencies' node in Solution Explorer

Tags: msbuild, .net-core, dotnet-sdk

I am writing custom MSBuild Target, that replaces some of `<PackageReference>` for `<ProjectReference>`, under specific conditions.

I have following msbuild target:

```
<Target Name="ApplyProjectRedirects"
      BeforeTargets="_GenerateDotnetCliToolReferenceSpecs;_GenerateProjectRestoreGraphPerFramework;_GenerateRestoreGraphWalkPerFramework;CollectPackageReferences;BeforeResolveReferences;ResolveAssemblyReferences"
      AfterTargets="PaketRestore">
```

```
    <ItemGroup>
      <!-- remove packages we are redirecting to projects, and include the projects -->
      <PackageReference Remove="@(ExcludePackageReferences)" />
      <ProjectReference Include="@(IncludeProjectPaths)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <!-- include the packages in visual studio 'nuget' display, so we know what we redirected -->
      <PackageReference Include="@(ExcludePackageReferences)">
        <ExcludeAssets>all</ExcludeAssets>
      </PackageReference>
    </ItemGroup>

</Target>
```

And my project references are invisible in Visual Studio Dependencies. Project compiles as intended, however.

I found out that `<ItemGroup>` with `<PackageReference>` inside target is respected, when the target is ran before `CollectPackageReferences`. However, I was unable to fill `<ProjectReference>` with any target, even the first one.

How does Visual Studio fill the Dependencies with solution projects?